# Imported CSV data back to CSV

Tags: powershell

I am new to Powershell and have a quick question.
The output I am playing with is from the sysinternals.com autorunsc tool in CSV format.
Purpose of the script is to search the CSV for certain binary names.

The import goes as expected but I cannot get it write my filtered info

```
$IOCFiles = "es.dll", "null.sys" 

$data = import-csv "D:\autoruns.csv" -header("Entry_Location","Entry","Enabled","Category","Description","Publisher","Image_Path","Launch_String","MD5","SHA-1","SHA-256") 

foreach ($K in $data)  
{ 
    foreach($element in $IOCFiles) 
    { 
        if ($k.Image_Path -match $element) 
        { 
            $hits = $k.Entry + "          " + $K.Publisher + "          " + $K.Image_Path 
            $hits | export-csv -Path c:\HITS.csv -NoTypeInformation
        } 
   } 
}
```

The above doesn't generate the actual data in the CSV but info on length of the values.
There are a number of good examples of import/exports but I didn't see one with the columns on import.  I have to use the column import method due to something similar I am playing with.

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Powershell makes this sort of thing pretty easy:

```
Import-csv "D:\autoruns.csv" -header("Entry_Location","Entry","Enabled","Category" |
  Where-Object{($IOCFiles -match $_.Image_Path) -ne $null} | 
  Select-Object Entry, Publisher, Image_Path |
  Export-CSV -Path c:\HITS.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

I haven't got the time to test that right now so there may be some issues with it, but that is the gist of it.

Comment: Thanks.  Looks like I was trying to do it the hard way.  Seems like this might work.  I will have to tweak it.  Seems like it doesnt want to populate the Publisher and Image Path columns.

Comment: I missed the scroll bar on your code. Just add in all the headers that you had, that should clear it up.

Comment: No problem!  I appreacite your time.
The code below builds the CSV the way I want.  The only issue now is that I would like to have an array of entries for the -match "null.sys".  

Import-csv "D:\autoruns.csv" -header("Entry_Location","Entry","Enabled","Category","Description","Publisher","ImagePath","Launch_String","MD5","SHA-1","SHA-256")|
  Where-Object{($_.ImagePath -match "null.sys")} |
  Select-Object Entry, Publisher, ImagePath |
  Export-CSV -Path c:\HITS.csv -NoTypeInformation

$IOCFiles = "Explorer.exe", "Notepad.exe"

Comment: I would suggest appending to your question with that code (because I'm too lazy to sort it out without line breaks) and explain exactly what you want and how what you are actually getting is wrong.

Comment: Thanks EBGreen.  I will post a new question.  You definetly pointed me in the right direction.  Take care